# Regular guy houses a genius suppressed personality

Tags: story-identification

What's the story where a regular guy turns out to have the repressed personality of an evil genius?. I read this story before 1985-ish. It was a Novel.

The protagonist is a janitor or something humble, but a musical prodigy. His former self was a super-genius with the mental ability to rule the world, but his friends staged an intervention and he agreed to compartmentalize his mind and put his brilliant-personality in a mental box and create a humble persona and live as that and forget the other personality, which he actually does. When his friends show back up, he thinks at first that they're out to destroy him, which in a way they are. They show up and say they need the other personality back for some good reason.

He agreed back when to repress his personality out of guilt over something, but later his friends need the old personality back to solve some big problem. But that would mean the end of the regular guy, who doesn't remember the former personality, so he doesn't want to do it.  There were hints that he's not so regular, he's a musical prodigy and can play a chess-like game.

Comment: What part of this story is fantasy or scifi?

Comment: I'll tell u that in real life, some of the most intelligent people deliberately seek mentally undemanding jobs so that they can use their work time to think. I have not only read about such people (Sidis, Bukowski, etc.) but have met, for example, a top chess player who worked as a mail carrier.

Answer (score 9):

You're looking for [Piers Anthony's *Macroscope*,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macroscope_(novel)) first published in 1969.

The primary protagonist is Ivo Archer, who is called upon by his childhood friend Brad Carpenter to contact the mysterious hyper-intelligent Schön, who is apparently in hiding, with Ivo his only outside contact.  Brad is part of a secret UN project involving a new technology, the titular Macroscope, which can be used to view close-up pictures from anywhere in the galaxy (and also into the past) and which is also picking up alien signals.

The most important signals, believed to contain the secrets to highly advanced alien technology, are apparently being deliberately jammed.  Brad believes that only Schön will be able to find a way to bypass the jamming signal (the "destroyer") and discover exactly what it is hiding.

It turns out that

> Ivo and Schön are alternate personalities, Ivo having been created by Schön at age 5 as a way of going into hiding.

Other major characters include Afra, who was Brad's girlfriend and

> Ivo's romantic interest after Brad's death

as well as Harold and Beatryx, who were also working on the Macroscope project.

You might also remember:

- Brad showing Ivo the history of various alien civilizations in the Macroscope, in an attempt to convince him that humanity is doomed unless the signals from the Macroscope can be deciphered.
- The destroyer signal, which drives insane anybody with sufficient intelligence to comprehend it.
- The traveller signal, one of those jammed by the destroyer signal until Ivo finds a way around it, which describes a suite of technology for interstellar travel.

(There were also thousands of other signals from different advanced civilizations, but as far as I recall none of them were of particular importance to the plot.)

- The protagonists stealing the Macroscope and escaping in a spaceship.
- The protagonists using one of the simplest technologies available from the traveller signal to turn themselves into liquid in order to survive extended 10G travel and escape the pursuing ships.
- A revelation about the reason for the destroyer signal which suggests that the aliens broadcasting it may have had good intentions in doing so,

> trying to prevent a repeat of a series of interstellar wars blamed upon the traveller signal.

- A final revelation about the reason for and nature of the traveller signal, which I won't reveal here.
- Conflict between Schön and Afra over Ivo's fate, which they agree to resolve by playing a game.
- A somewhat ambiguous ending.

*Macroscope* was quite different from Piers Anthony's later works, and not entirely to my taste, but certainly a striking and important work.  It was nominated for the Hugo Award for Best Novel in 1970.

Comment: A detail that stuck in my mind: Schön sends through Ivo the message “my pawn is pinned,” meaning that Schön will not move Ivo aside because doing so would allow him to understand the mystery signal, which would damage Schön's sanity.  It is harmless to those, like Ivo, who cannot understand it.